# EntityFramework BulkInsert extension and Triggers?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, triggers

I'm using the EntityFramework [BulkInsert extension](https://efbulkinsert.codeplex.com/) to insert large datasets into my database. However, there is an `AFTER INSERT` trigger on the table that I'm inserting data into that doesn't seem to be firing. Is this a limitation of the extension or is there a way to ensure that the trigger fires when the operation completes?

Comment: what database are you using?

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out I just wasn't looking hard enough. There are some overloads for the main `BulkInsert` method that are not listed anywhere in the documentation and I could not find them through any Google searches, but one of the overloads allow for flags. One of the flags is `SqlBulkCopyOptions.FireTriggers`.

It is used like: `context.BulkInsert(values, SqlBulkCopyOptions.FireTriggers)`. Using this method, each row is processed individually by the trigger, and everything works as it should.

**EDIT:** Answer comment

> can you explain what the CheckConstraint will do?

A constraint is when you add some checks such as the value must be between `10` and `50` to be valid and inserted.

So if you don't check constraint, a value of `5` will be inserted without a problem even if out of range. If you check constraint, an error will be throw:

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "CHK_ColumnWithConstraint". The conflict occurred in database "db_2560", table "dbo.Customers", column 'ColumnWithConstraint'.
The statement has been terminated.
```

Here is an online example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/AMgTYQ

That's why I recommend `SqlBulkCopyOptions.FireTriggers | SqlBulkCopyOptions.CheckConstraints`

If the table have a trigger, you probably when to fire them. If a column has a constraint, you probably want the operation to throw an error if the value is not valid with the check.

Comment: I recommend you adding also CheckConstraint (SqlBulkCopyOptions.FireTriggers | SqlBulkCopyOptions.CheckConstraints)

Comment: @JonathanMagnan, can you explain what the CheckConstraint will do?